# How Grafana is Collecting the Data from opentsdb ( Backend Storage : Hbase )?

Tags: hbase, grafana, opentsdb

I am a Beginner to this opentsdb project. So I hope the expert person will clarify will my doubts.

How Grafana is collecting complete data from opentsdb server and by what method they are collecting all metrics,tags,values etc.

**OR**

They are accessing the Hbase directly ? If so How it was collecting complete data.

Answer (score 0):

No, Grafana uses only the HTTP API provided by OpenTSDB. It is fully described in http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/index.html